# nesting table inside a <td> to match the <th> of outside table

Tags: html, css, angular

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>
<table style="border:1px solid;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">Type</th>
      <th colspan="2">Client</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Currency</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Amount</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Monthly Total</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Yearly Total</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Id</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Customer</td>
      <td colspan="4">
        <table style="width:100%">
          <tr>
            <td>Client A</td>
            <td>1234</td>
            <td>USD</td>
            <td>200</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Client B</td>
            <td>5678</td>
            <td>USD</td>
            <td>200</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>300</td>
      <td>500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Vendor</td>
      <td colspan="4">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Client C</td>
            <td>5678</td>
            <td>GBP</td>
            <td>100</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>300</td>
      <td>500</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

</html>
```

I have to achieve the above structure , but I am unable to align the inner table to match the width of the  from the outer table . tried many things but unable to do it. Could some one please help me ?

So I have a two *ngFor nested , the first one is for the outer table tbody and the second one is for a row for the inner table.

Answer (score 1):

Should you be nesting the table?  I would use rowspan instead otherwise your table structure is not semantically correct

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>
<table style="border:1px solid;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">Type</th>
      <th colspan="2">Client</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Currency</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Amount</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Monthly Total</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Yearly Total</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Id</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">Customer</td>
      <td>Client A</td>
      <td>1234</td>
      <td>USD</td>
      <td>200</td>
      <td rowspan="2">300</td>
      <td rowspan="2">500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Client B</td>
      <td>5678</td>
      <td>USD</td>
      <td>200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Vendor</td>
      <td>Client C</td>
      <td>5678</td>
      <td>GBP</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>300</td>
      <td>500</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing can be very fiddly. I suggest you save yourself the headache with:

`<th>Client Name</th><th>Client ID</th>`

If you *really have* to achieve this structure, use `colspan and rowspan`.